# Why does the indefinite integral $\int \sin(x) \sec^2(x) dx$ give different answers for different substitutions?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, substitution

If I solve
$$I=\int \sin(x) \sec^2(x) dx$$
with the substitution $u=\cos(x)$ I get the answer
$$I = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2(x)$$
But if I try with $u = \tan(x)$ I get the answer
$$I = \frac{1}{2}\tan^2(x)$$
What's going on? How can I get them to match?

Comment: $\sec^2=\tan^2+1$. Never forget the constant of integration!!!!

Comment: Those two solutions differ by a constant, hence they are both correct, or both incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But they are the same (up to a constant): since
$$ \sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}=1, $$
dividing by $\cos^2{x}$ implies that
$$ \tan^2{x}+1 = \sec^2{x}.  $$

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, these are equivalent because
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sec^2 x + C_1 = \frac{1}{2}\tan^2 x +C_2,
$$
albeit with different values of constant.

---

Having said that, you have integrated incorrectly $-$ you should find that the actual integral is
$$
I = \sec x + C
$$
The first substitution works, whereas the second doesn't. Try it again and comment below if you have any trouble.